# How can I debug txJSON-Rpc calls using a javascript client and Python server?

Tags: python, rpc, json-rpc

I have implemented a wxPython app, that also has a Twisted txJSONrpc server in it. This is my RPC "server"; I can call it using a TCP socket and issue commands.

There is a Python test script called client_subhandled.py in txjsonrpc that I used to test, and it calls and receives an answer from the RPC server, so Python client/server communication works.

However, I need to make JSON RPC calls from javascript, not from Python. To do that I have used a small java applet that allows you to open a TCP socket from javascript and read and write to/from it (java_socket_bridge.js). This also works, I have tested it not using the JSON RPC protocol, but sending and receiving plain text using a simple twisted echo protocol.

The problem is that using javascript as a client, I can't seem to get rpc JSON calls to work. Is there a way to debug incoming JSON rpc calls in txJSONrpc? I would ideally like to see what JSON objects come in in the server to see if they're compliant.

Thanks!

```
from twisted.internet import wxreactor  # socket library
wxreactor.install()                     # for using twisted along with wxPython

# using netstring TCP protocol
from txjsonrpc.netstring import jsonrpc
from twisted.web import server

# import twisted reactor *only after* installing wxreactor
from twisted.internet import reactor

myreactor = reactor

def register(application):
    # initialise and run the TWISTED reactor
    reactor.registerWxApp(application)
    #rpcCom.myreactor.listenTCP(9000, rpcCom.EchoServerFactory())
    reactor.listenTCP(9000, factory)
    reactor.run()

class Example(jsonrpc.JSONRPC):
    """An example object to be published."""

    def jsonrpc_echo(self, x):
        """Return all passed args."""
        print "echo called"
        return x

class Testing(jsonrpc.JSONRPC):

    def jsonrpc_getList(self):
        """Return a list."""
        return [1,2,3,4,'a','b','c','d']

class Math(jsonrpc.JSONRPC):
    """
    An example object to be published.
    """
    def jsonrpc_add(self, a, b):
        """
        Return sum of arguments.
        """
        return a + b

factory = jsonrpc.RPCFactory(Example)
factory.putSubHandler('math', Math)
factory.putSubHandler('testing', Testing)

factory.addIntrospection()
```

Comment: [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/ )

Comment: hi @yanjost, I have installed wireshark, but it can't capture client-server traffic on the same machine: http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback

Comment: Have you tried the different recipes on this page as workarounds for the loopback problem  ?

Comment: Ah, rawcap.exe seems to do the trick under Windows 7. I'm having other troubles now (netstring isn't really readable or comparable in packets) but the answer is correct in principle. Thanks yanjost, please add your comment as an answer, so I can mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) ?

Be careful, it seems like there are some issues when capturing on localhost ;)